# Stop Matlab timer from within its callback (after outside input/event)

Tags: matlab

I am running a long data preload within a timer callback, and I would like to be able to stop the callback halfway through with an outside input (for instance, the click of a GUI button).
The `stop()` function will stop the timer calls, but not the callback function itself.

Here is a simple example:

```
timerh = timer('TimerFcn' , @TimerCallback,'StartDelay' , 1, 'ExecutionMode' , 'singleShot');
NeedStopping = false;

start(timerh)

disp('Running')
pause(1)
disp('Trying to stop')
NeedStopping = true;


function TimerCallback(obj, event)
% Background data loading in here code in here; in this example, 
% the callback simply displays numbers from 1 to 100

    for k = 1 : 100
        drawnow();  % Should allow Matlab to do other stuff
        NeedStopping = evalin('base' , 'NeedStopping');
        if NeedStopping
            disp('Should stop now')
            return
        end
        disp(k)
        pause(0.1)
    end
end
```

I expect this script to display numbers between 1 and (approximately) ten, but the timer callback does not stop until 100.
Strangely, the code reaches the line just before before the `pause(1)` and correctly prints 'Running', but then it stops there and waits for the timer to finish.
Even more perplexing, if I change the 1 second pause to 0.9 seconds, the timer stops immediately with this output:

> Running
>
> Trying to stop
>
> Should stop now

I am aware that Matlab is mostly single-threaded, but I thought the `drawnow()` function should allow it to process other stuff.

---

Edit: Specific use behind my question:
I have a GUI with a "next" button that loads several images and shows them all side by side. The images are large so loading takes time; therefore, while the user looks at the pictures, I want to preload the next set. This can be done in the background with a timer, and it works.
However, if the user clicks "next" before the preloading has finished, I need to stop it, show the current images, and launch the preloading for the next step. Hence, the timer needs to stop during callback execution.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are trying to achieve with this code, and it only losely ressemble the question in the title. In your code you are trying to stop the timer from **outside** its callback, you are trying to stop it by setting a variable in the base workspace (if that is what you want you could simply do `stop(timerh)` instead of using a cousin function of `eval`). We have your code attempt and a description of what it does, now please describe more accurately the behaviour you initialy try to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback: I tried to clarify my intent. `timer()` is not good because it will stop further timer calls, but not the currently running callback.

Comment: You are right, stopping the timer itself will not stop execution of the callback if it has started already. On the other hand, you are using the `singleshot` mode of the timer, to start the execution of **one** single function (the callback), which you would like to be interruptible. You do not need to use a timer for that. The function could be the callback of any button or element of your gui. On the bad news, neither the timer callback or a standard button callback will run in a different process and allow you to do stuff while it's running.

Comment: Not really; the timer runs in the background in my GUI, and I am able to do other stuff in the meanwhile. But I need to stop it if I want to change dataset before it has finished loading the data for the current one.

Comment: yes the timer _counts_ time in the background and let you do other stuff during that time, but when the timer callback actually starts to execute, it takes over the main process and nothing else is going to be excuted in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a demo of how to set up an interruptible `callback`. The way your example is set up I didn't see the need for an actual timer so I made it as a standard button callback.

note: *If you are dead set on using it for a timer you can use exactly the same solution, just assign the `startProcess` callback to the timer instead of the gui button.*

```
function h = interuptible_callback_demo

% generate basic gui with 2 buttons
h = create_gui ;
guidata( h.fig , h )

% create application data which will be used to interrupt the process
setappdata( h.fig , 'keepRunning' , true )

end


function startProcess(hobj,~)
    h = guidata( hobj ) ;
    % set the 'keepRunning' flag
    setappdata( h.fig , 'keepRunning' , true )
    % toggle the button states
    h.btnStart.Enable = 'off' ;
    h.btnStop.Enable  = 'on' ;

    nGrainOfSand = 1e6 ;
    for k=1:nGrainOfSand
        % first check if we have to keep running
        keepRunning = getappdata( h.fig , 'keepRunning' ) ;

        if keepRunning
            % This is where you do your lenghty stuff
            % we'll count grains of sand for this demo ...
            h.lbl.String = sprintf('Counting grains of sands: %d/%d',k,nGrainOfSand) ;
            pause(0.1) ;
        else
            % tidy up then bail out (=stop the callback)
            h.lbl.String = sprintf('Counting interrupted at: %d/%d',k,nGrainOfSand) ;
            % toggle the button states
            h.btnStart.Enable = 'on' ;
            h.btnStop.Enable = 'off' ;
            return
        end
    end
end

function stopProcess(hobj,~)
    h = guidata( hobj ) ;
    % modify the 'keepRunning' flag
    setappdata( h.fig , 'keepRunning' , false )
end

function h = create_gui
    h.fig = figure('units','pixel','Position',[200 200 350 200]) ;
    h.btnStart = uicontrol('style','pushbutton','string','Start process',...
                            'units','pixel','Position',[50 100 100 50],...
                            'Callback',@startProcess) ;
    h.btnStop  = uicontrol('style','pushbutton','string','Stop process',...
                            'units','pixel','Position',[200 100 100 50],...
                            'Callback',@stopProcess,'enable','off') ;
    h.lbl  = uicontrol('style','text','string','','units','pixel','Position',[50 20 200 50]) ;
end
```

To see it in action:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hoki, this works and the timer version you suggest is exactly what I am doing in my own GUI. So why doesn'it it work in my minimal script example?
BTW, I edited the original post to explain why I resorted to a timer.

Comment: not sure exactly but in your example your timer have a `StartDelay` of 1 second, and then you have a `pause(1)` instruction just after you start the timer. So the timer and the main process will start to count 1 second in parrallel. If the main process reaches it first (it definitely does when you set the pause to 0.9 second), then it will change the stop flag before the timer actually started, so when the timer finally starts executing callback, it reads the flag to stop and never really do anything.

Comment: on the other case, if the timer counts first to 1s, when it's callback starts executing the main process is paused, the `drawnow()` instruction just flush the graphic event queue, but does not give execution time to the main process ... so the timer keeps counting to 100, then give back control to the main thread which will finally set up your flag `stop` (but your timer doesn't need it it's already finished).

Comment: "drawnow() instruction just flush the graphic event queue, but does not give execution time to the main process". That answers it for me!

Comment: In my solution it works because the `stop` flag is set by another `callback`, not by the main process. `callback` functions have a mechanism to interrupt each other, if the right `Interruptible` property is set. The main process cannot _interrupt_ a callback process.